# SQL oracle with joining tables and Max functions

Tags: sql, oracle

Some help please? Just a noob here starting to learn how to write SQL and ran into this problem. I know how to use the `MAX` function but I can't figure out how to join all these requirements together. I have two tables, `Accounts` and `Books` (below is an example of the data)

```
Accounts                                       
ID Series   YesorNot    Dated Filed     Plan Year       
1   123     Yes         06/12/2015      2015        
2   123     No          06/12/2015      2015        
3   145     Yes         06/06/2015      2015
4   145     No          02/02/2015      2014        
5   198     Yes         02/03/2015      2015        
6   187     Yes         02/14/2013      2013            
7   153     Yes         01/02/2011      2011        

Books       
Primary Key Date Created    ID
1           06/13/2015      123
2           06/12/2015      123
3           06/07/2015      145
4           02/02/2015      145
5           02/03/2015      198
```

Two tables: `Accounts` and `Books`
Looking for:
1. Data that exists in both tables by the Project ID = Primary Key
2. I only want one unqiue Series (Series also = ID)
3. I want the `MAX` (most recent) value of Plan Year, and then if there are duplicates for Plan Year, I need the `MAX` (most recent) value of Date Created.
4. I just need the columns `Project ID`, `Series`, `YesorNot`, `Date Filed`, `Plan Year` so my output should be like this:

```
Project ID  Series  YesorNot  Dated Filed Plan Year     
1           123     Yes       06/12/2015  2015          
3           145     Yes       06/06/2015  2015          
4           145     No        02/02/2015  2014          
5           198     Yes       02/03/2015  2015
```

Comment: This is difficult to do (due to condition 3) without creating sets of temporary tables and possibly having a few outputs. If YesOrNot = No does that always indicate multiple rows for the same series in Accounts with the same Plan Year?

Comment: What do you mean by "data that exists in both tables by the Project ID = Primary Key"? What is Project ID? Then - aren't the two tables matched by Series in the first table and ID in the second table? I hope you don't have tables that are "matched" by more than a pair of columns!

Comment: @BenHamilton - are you familiar with analytic functions?

Comment: @mathguy no, I am not sure they're available in Ingres which is the main DBMS I've worked with. OP is using Oracle but I've never worked with it.

Comment: @Tiffanyyim - What happens if there is a tie by Plan Year, and the "series" does not appear in the Books table?

Answer (score 0):

First join the tables:

```
SELECT B.Primary_Key as Project_ID, A.Series, A.YesorNot, A.Date_Filed, A.Plan_Year
FROM Books B
JOIN Accounts A ON B.ID = A.Series
```

You should have been able to get this far on your own (and you should have posted it as part of the question) -- if you can't I'd say find a different career.  Assuming you could now the slightly harder part.

Now we add a row number based on your criteria

```
ROW_NUMBER() PARTITION BY (B.Primary_Key, A.Series, A.YesorNot, A.Date_Filed ORDER BY A.Date_Year DESC, B.Date_Created DESC) AS RN
```

Now just take the first of the row number.

```
SELECT Project_ID, Series, YesorNot, Date_Filed, Plan_Year
FROM (
  SELECT B.Primary_Key as Project_ID, A.Series, A.YesorNot, A.Date_Filed, A.Plan_Year,
         ROW_NUMBER() PARTITION BY (B.Primary_Key, A.Series, A.YesorNot, A.Date_Filed ORDER BY A.Date_Year DESC, B.Date_Created DESC) AS RN
  FROM Books B
  JOIN Accounts A ON B.ID = A.Series
) X
WHERE RN = 1
```